# Read MultiForm Post data in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, multipartform-data

I am trying to read Multipart form data that is posted via an `HTTP Post` API in `MVC4`. There are three parameters that I am sending, which I want to retrieve and use. What is the right way to do this. I have looked around on SO, and basically am doing something like this

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
        {
            // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
            string token = provider.Contents.First(x => x.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"token\"").ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            try
            {
                // Read the form data.
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
            }
        }
```

I am not getting any values in the  `provider.Contents` field. Is this the right way to try and read this data?

This is the format of data being sent as seen on Fiddler

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary41Q2pJ6ku9QScZJ7
```

And the web form content disposition values are so

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type" 1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="debug"    0
```

The equivalent in PHP/Zend that I am trying to migrate from is `Zend_Rest_Controller_Action.GetParams`